# converting a string to an array and I keep getting an array with 1 object with the string crammed in that single index

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to ruby and trying to create a method that takes a string and returns an array with each letter as their own index in an array.

```
def validate_word(word)
  w=[]
  word.downcase!
  w << word.split(//) 
  return w
end
validate_word("abcABC")

=> [["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]]
```

I would like it to return

```
=>["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Thank you for looking at my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you do not need to create a new array, since `String#split` returns array which you want. Also, Ruby returns last string of a method by default, so you can write:

```
def validate_word(word)
  word.downcase! 
  word.split(//) # or you can chain methods: word.downcase.split('')
end
validate_word("abcABC")
=> ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Note: do not use methods with exclamation mark (`downcase!`) except cases when you want modify source object. Use alternative methods(`downcase`) instead.

Comment: this totally works but I was hoping to have an array object that I could further manipulate when expanding my method to include more features. Sorry I was not more precise in my question.

Comment: @SinGar you can expand your method without creating additional array, just create a variable (`chars = word.split('')`) or call other method on array (`word.split('').manipulation`).